# Warning: PDO::prepare(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 when update

Tags: pdo

I want to update several tables as below:

```
for ($i=0; $i <count($tablesnames); $i++) {

    $update3=$pdo->prepare('UPDATE :surveytable SET `postrecords`=:newrecord WHERE `id`=:id');
//var_dump()here
    $update3->bindValue(':surveytable', $tablesnames[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $update3->bindValue(':newrecord',$newrecord,PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $update3->bindValue(':id',$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $update3->execute();

}
```

Check the var_dump result,`$tablesnames[$i]` and `$newrecord`are `string`,`$id` is `int`,`$update3` is `false`.
Seemed everything ok but failed,

> Warning: PDO::prepare(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? SET `postrecords`=? WHERE `id`=?'

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Unfortunately) you can't use parameters for your tablename in your prepared statement. You can only use those for **data** literals. So `UPDATE :surveytable` is invalid.

As per [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> Parameter markers can represent a complete **data literal only**. Neither
>   part of literal, nor keyword, **nor identifier**, nor whatever arbitrary
>   query part can be bound using parameters.

When you (**completely!!!**) trust your source of `$tablesnames`, use

```
'UPDATE `' . $tablesnames[i]` . '` SET `postrecords`=:newrecord WHERE `id`=:id'
```

instead

Comment: which mean cannot fully avoid sql injection,sad!

Comment: Depends on the source of `$tablesnames`. When this is user-input (e.g. POST-data, even the names of POST-data), you should definitely validate it before using it within your query. For example using an `in_array` whith a list of your existing tablenames or a `preg_match` with a regular expression that would only allow valid tablenames. (edit:) Although using user-input for tablenames is something I always try to avoid (due to this kind of concerns).